# How to copy file input field into my root web app with javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, file

I have an application using Javascript to create a form.

In the form there will be an input of type file. I'd like to copy that file into my web app (i.e mywebapp/filestored) so i can send a relative URL to my server and store it in my database.

How could i do that with javascript ?

Comment: I use a send form in javascript so i can do that copy server - side 

But i'd like to know if it's possible through JavaScript directly

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) and [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2), you will need to use multipart/form-data encryption type to send your file to your backend.

The part of parsing the data and store them into a db, has to do with the language you use in your backend.
e.g for node.js you will need a module like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to parse the data received.

Comment: Thanks, so copy won't be possible client side through javascript i guess ?

Comment: @AodRen since javascript is pure clientside, how are you supposed do store data on the server? if that's possible it would be a big security issue. therefore you have to send the data to a controller on the server who is handling the storage and the insertion into the database and returns the success or error back to your javascript.

Comment: Thanks @RaphaelMüller; i'm learning web programmation therefore i missed the obvious security issue.